# ScrollView Won't Scroll Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this grid which I want on my app.  However it is too wide for the iPhone screen and so I want to use a scroll view.  This will scroll left to right so as you can see the full grid. I have got the scroll view out on my storyboard at the moment and I have put the code in for it to work which is typed bellow. But it won't work when I build the application.  I think that my problem is that I haven't linked it up in the outlets section on the ViewController.  However I can't link it up, as there is no button there that I can drag out and put on the ScrollView.  There is two things there and that is View - View and searchDisplayController - *(Nothing)*. So I can't find the Scroller button that should be there. If someone could help it would be mostly appreciated.

Code:

ViewController.h:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
```

ViewController.m

```
[Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[Scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(476, 476))];
```

This is a Screen shot of what I mean about the scroller not being in the outlets tab.
I am on the ViewController that the scroll view is on.  No i would think that there should be Scroller in that outlets tab under View-View so that I can then drag it out and put it over the ScrollView. Maybe I am wrong but I think that, that would be the way for it to work.

[image]

Screenshot of the Scroll View Connections in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: Where did you put this .m code? In what method? And I don't understand why you "haven't linked it up in the outlets section on the ViewController" or what you've talking about with a button in the scrollview.

Comment: It is in the `- (void)ViewDidLoad`  If you don't understand I will edit my original post and add a screen shot of what I mean.

Comment: OK, and put that code in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead.

Comment: Do you understand my Screen Shot?  Shouldn't there be a tab that is called Scroller that I can then link to the Scroll View in the ViewController?

Comment: No that's correct. You're looking at the view's outlet collection and that's correct. Click on your scrollview then take a similar screenshot and post it here so we can see whether that's connected as a referencing outlet to your file's owner.

Comment: You're right, you haven't connected it properly. I'm running out of the house now, but will try to find a link for you to show you how to properly connect your outlet to your view. It's easy, but I don't have time to show you myself right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65887/discussion-between-benjamin-mcintyre-and-lyndsey-scott).

Comment: This video tutorial should help: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tYS0sCFWOSo

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to viewDidLayoutSubviews method if you are using iOS 7 devices

```
[Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[Scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(476, 476))];
```

Comment: Should I still have it under `viewDidLoad` too?

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre No.

Comment: Do you see my problem with the screen shot that I added. Should there be a Scroller thing there that I can then drag onto my ScrollView?

Comment: from ios 8 there is no contentsize method required. but to run the code for ios 7 and below... need to set scroller in viewDidLayoutSubviews with auto layout.